# How to see the activity history of a resource on Google Cloud Platform (GCP)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How do I see the history of a resource/asset on GCP?

For example I have a compute instance `instance1`, and I want to know what config change has been made to it in the past few days.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so there are two resources that may come in handy for you. Not sure if you're working on the command line or the console, but here's one way to see activity logs on a compute instance: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/activity-logs

Apparently it will be deprecated in the future, though, so you might want to just go straight to the audit logs: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/audit-logging

Good luck!

Comment: thanks! audit log does contains what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using [Cloud Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview).

In particular, they have an API to [view asset history](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/viewing-asset-history)
 given an asset.

In your case, you can do

```sh
gcloud asset get-history --project='$PROJECT_ID' \
  --asset-names='//compute.googleapis.com/projects/$PROJECT_ID/zo\
nes/$ZONE/instances/$INSTANCE' \
  --start-time='2020-06-01T12:00:23.000Z' \
  --end-time='2020-06-04T13:01:21.045Z' \
  --content-type='resource'
```

Comment: Seems this allows me to locate the resource in a more precise fashion than audit log!